# Better way to use Ruby/Sinatra to pass data to Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, haml, highcharts

I'm generally of the opinion that if it ain't broke don't fix it, but my current solution to this issue (though it does work) seems really ugly. I am using Ruby, Sinatra, Haml, and Highcharts, and I'd like to be able to pass data grabbed in Ruby and send to Highcharts.

Currently, I'm essentially just creating a string object out of the entire Highcharts javascript and interpolating the ruby data into that. This works, but should I be taking a completely different approach to this? Here's exactly what I'm doing:

I've defined a HighChart class with several properties that I want to be able to change via Ruby (e.g. chart title, data, etc). The example below (which works!) only sets two of these properties, leaving the rest as default:

```
    get '/' do
      @chart = HighChart.new(options={
                    :title_text => "Test Title",
                    :series_data => 
                    {
                    'Calvin' => [10, 2, 17],
                    'Hobbes' => [11, 14, 6]
                    }
                  }
                )
      haml :index
    end
```

I'm using Haml's javascript filter in the view:

```
:javascript
  #{@chart.chart_js}
```

So far so good. The ugly part is the chart_js method. I have simply copied the full text of the HighChart javascript, pasted it in as a string, and then used Ruby interpolation to grab the variables from the HighChart object created in the controller:

```
    def chart_js  
      chart_js = "
      var chart1;
      $(document).ready(function() {

  chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({

     chart: {

        renderTo: '#{render_to}',

        type: '#{chart_type}'

     },

     title: {

        text: '#{title_text}'

     },

     xAxis: {

        categories: #{x_categories}

     },

     yAxis: {

        title: {

           text: '#{y_categories}'

        }

     },

     series: [#{get_data_js(series_data)}]

  });

 });
  "
end
```

And just in case it's helpful, here's the first part of the HighChart object class definition:

```
    class HighChart
attr_accessor :render_to, :chart_type, :title_text, :x_categories, 
              :y_categories, :series_data

    def initialize(options={})
      self.render_to = options[:render_to] || 'container'
      self.chart_type = options[:chart_type] || 'bar'
      self.title_text = options[:title_text] || 'Fruit Consumption'
      self.x_categories = options[:x_categories] || ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      self.y_categories = options[:y_categories] || 'Fruit eaten'
      self.series_data = options[:series_data] || {'Jane' => [1, 0, 4], 
                                                  'Bobbert' => [5, 7, 3],
                                                  'Zach' => [10, 2, 1]
                                                  }
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a view specifically for the Highcharts JS, and then use instance variables (eg. @render_to, @chart_type, etc.).  That won't really clean up the code that much, but it will get rid of some of the "wrongness" of having a giant view string in your controller.

Fundamentally though there's not much else you can do; you have a bunch of server-side info, and it has to be written to the client (in the specific Highcharts format).  There's just no getting around that.

The only other suggestion I can offer is to use intermediate JS variables.  This would let you keep all of the JS in the view (without a JS-only view), and then you would just need to set some JS variables.  This would look something like this:

```
var RENDER_TO = "@render_to";
var CHART_TYPE = "@chart_type";
// ...
$(document).ready(function() {
  chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
       renderTo: RENDER_TO,
       ....
```

Now this actually involves more code, but it would let you totally separate your onReady code from the server-value-writing code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I think the part that was bugging me the most was having all that javascript in a string and in the controller, so I took your advice and separated that out into a partial. That solves the problem of having all that javascript in a string. Much more comfortable with this now--thanks for the help!